# How to update after an action listener is finished

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have created a list of elements with two buttons. The first is "accept", the other is "decline". Whichever button I press, I want it to be removed from my datatable and have my list updated without the removed element.
My problem is that my list cannot be updated quickly enough, so I have to wait one second.

```
<p:commandButton value="Accept" update="mydatatable"
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{mymessage}"
                                target="#{myView.accept}" />
                        </p:commandButton>
```

My view. accept

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "element removed", ""));
```

What I want to do: execute the update once MyView.accept() is completely finished. I tried to change update by oncomplete/on success but I didn't get any satisfying result. I m looking for something like `oncomplete = update="mydatatable"`

How could I do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes)

Comment: Thanks for your link

Answer (score 0):

Even if the message is not published anymore, someone gave the almost right answer to my problem (which helped me a lot,thanks)

the right answer was `update="@this,mydatatable"`

Comment: And how does this remove the button from the datatable?

Comment: The buttons are displayed in every row of the datatable. When the list is updated, the element is not part of the list anymore and its buttons are gone too.

Comment: But then there is no need to `update="@this"`.... Unless you have some other problem for which this is a workaround... (http://www.xyproblem.info)